# Python library (or how to roll my own) alternative to Dig

Tags: python, dns

Obviously I can simply use `subprocess` and wrap `dig`, but I'd prefer a bit of platform independence.

I need a library that meets the following criteria:

- Python only (supports python3. Preferably without running 2to3)
- Can get the CERT record for a domain
- Is BSD/MIT or other permissive (non-GPL) license. LGPL could be OK.

Comment: A related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237068/1651408 recommends `dnspython`.

Comment: @DeerHunter - `dnspython3` works for me. Go ahead & post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dnspython3](http://www.dnspython.org/) may be what you're looking for. [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191450/koblas): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237068/1651408

- Python 2 (`pip install dnspython`) **and** 3 (`pip install dnspython3`) versions (version >=2.4)
- `dns.resolver` is the main class for `dig`-type work
- The license is very permissive:

> ```
> Copyright (C) 2001-2003 Nominum, Inc.
>
> Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software and its
> documentation for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted,
> provided that the above copyright notice and this permission notice
> appear in all copies.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND NOMINUM DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
> WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL NOMINUM BE LIABLE FOR
> ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
> WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
> ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT
> OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
> ```

Latest update: September 2013.

Own experience: works out of the box.

Comment: `pip install dnspython3` for Python3. `dnspython` for 2.x

Comment: (oops - looks like you left off the `3` ;)